# How to make a view 100% window height?

Tags: react-native

I'm brand new to react native. I'm trying to figure out how to make a box full height.

I have tried to add flex property to both container and view, but the height is not 100%.

```
export default class LinksScreen extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff', flexGrow: 1 }}>
          <Text>Hallo</Text>
        </View>

      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the ScrollView with a View that has height. `ScrollViews must have a bounded height in order to work`. You can read more details about that here: `https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview`

Do it something like below:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{height: 80}} >
          <ScrollView
            ...
```

**EDIT**

Your code actually works. Maybe you just want to see if your scrollview works when the whole screen is occupied. Try this below and you will see, I simply multiplied the text contents 80 times:

```
render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#fff", flexGrow: 1 }}>
          {Array(80)
            .fill(1)
            .map((item, index) => (
              <Text>Hallo {index}</Text>
            ))}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `flex:1`

Give `height:"100%"
      width: "100%"`